# Merging column headers and adding vertical separators

Tags: tabularx, rotating, threeparttable

I would like to achieve 2 things in the below table and can't figure out how:

1. I want to merge the headers from the first row to run across the columns in the second row in order to show that row 2 is a subdimension of row 1.
2. I want the cmidrule between row 1 and row 2 to have breaks after column 4 and column 6 in order to show that those are different dimensions.

The following image shows the original design from another context that I would like to apply:

[image]

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass[authoryear,11pt]{elsarticle}

%Packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable, lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
%\usepackage{endfloat,threeparttable,longtable} %package puts tables and figures to the end
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blauelsevier,urlcolor=blauelsevier, citecolor=blauelsevier]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify{\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}


%\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

%\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\small
\singlespacing
%\centering
\sisetup{detect-weight}

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{\label{tab:tab_opening} Opening of formal insolvency proceedings}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
                       lCCCCCCC@{}}
    \toprule

    \bfseries 
        & \multicolumn{3}{C}{\bfseries Proceedings opened because of}
    & \multicolumn{2}{C}{\bfseries Debtors allowed to file for}
    & \multicolumn{1}{C}{\bfseries Creditors allowed to file for}\\
        \cmidrule{2-8}
        \bfseries Country
    & \multicolumn{1}{C}{\bfseries illiquidity}
    & \multicolumn{1}{C}{\bfseries imminent illiquidity}
    & \multicolumn{1}{C}{\bfseries over-indebtedness}
        & \multicolumn{1}{C}{\bfseries restructuring}
    & \multicolumn{1}{C}{\bfseries liquidation}
        & \multicolumn{1}{C}{\bfseries restructuring}
    & \multicolumn{1}{C}{\bfseries liquidation}\\


        \midrule
Austria & Yes   & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & No    & Yes \cr
Belgium & Yes   & Yes   & No    & Yes   & Yes   & No    & Yes \cr
Denmark & Yes   & No    & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr
Finland & Yes   & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr
France & Yes   & No    & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr
Germany & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr
Greece & Yes   & No    & No    & Yes   & Yes   & No    & Yes \cr
Ireland & Yes   & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr
Italy & Yes   & No    & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr
Luxembourg & Yes   & No    & No    & Yes   & Yes   & No    & Yes \cr
Netherlands & Yes   & Yes   & No    & Yes   & Yes   & No    & Yes \cr
Portugal & Yes   & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr
Spain & Yes   & Yes   & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr
Sweden & Yes   & No    & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr
United Kingdom & Yes   & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \cr
Brazil & Yes   & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & No    & Yes \cr
China & Yes   & Yes   & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr
India & Yes   & No    & No    & No    & Yes   & No    & Yes \cr
Russia & Yes   & No    & No    & Yes   & Yes   & No    & Yes \cr
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \cr
United States of America & Yes   & No    & No    & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \cr

        \bottomrule


\end{tabularx}%

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\labelsep0.0em
\item Notes: This table provides an overview of the provisions for the opening of insolvency proceedings in each country of the sample. Columns (1) to (3) provide the available grounds to file for insolvency. Firms that are not able to make any due payments are considered illiquid. Firms that are able to foresee illiquidity in the near future are considered imminently illiquid. Firms with more liabilities than assets and a lack of positive business prospects are considered over-indebted. Columns (4) to (7) inform whether debtors and/or creditors are allowed to file for liquidation and/or restructuring proceedings.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\par

\end{sidewaystable}

%\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution based on `makecell` and its `\rothead` command.You don't hve to use the `sidewaystable` environment. I also loaded the `geometry` package to have more sensible margins. I removed  `mathabx` which has problems with `lmodern`(duplicate commands), and `color` since you load `xcolor`. Finally I grouped packages by categories to get a shorter preamble:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,11pt]{elsarticle}
%Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, eurosym}%, mathabx
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, longtable, tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{endfloat} %package puts tables and figures to the end
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blauelsevier,urlcolor=blauelsevier, citecolor=blauelsevier]{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\small
\singlespacing
\centering
\sisetup{detect-weight}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\settowidth{\rotheadsize}{\small\bfseries restructuring?}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{bc}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{\label{tab:tab_opening} tbd}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l*{8}{C}@{}}
\toprule
\bfseries
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead[b]{Can proceedings be\\ opened because of ...}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[b]{Are debtors\\ allowed to \\ file for ...}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[b]{Are creditors\\ allowed to\\ file for ...}}\\[-1ex]
 \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(r){5-6} \cmidrule(r){7-8}\addlinespace[-1ex]
    \thead[lb]{Country}
    & \rothead{illiquidity?}
    & \rothead{imminent illiquidity?}
    & \rothead{over-indebtedness?}
    & \rothead{liquidation?}
    & \rothead{restructuring?}
    & \rothead{liquidation?}
     & \rothead{restructuring?}\\[-1ex]
    \midrule
    Austria & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & No\\
    Belgium & Yes & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & No \\
    Denmark & Yes & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
    Finland & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
    France & Yes & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
    Germany & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
    Greece & Yes & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & No \\
    Ireland & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
    Italy & Yes & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
    Luxembourg & Yes & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & No \\
    Netherlands & Yes & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & No \\
    Portugal & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
    Spain & Yes & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
    Sweden & Yes & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
    United Kingdom & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\%
    \addlinespace[2ex]
    Brazil & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & No \\
    China & Yes & Yes & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
    India & Yes & No & No & Yes & No & Yes & No \\
    Russia & Yes & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & No \\
    \addlinespace[2ex]
    \makecell[lc]{United States\\ of America} & Yes & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\labelsep0.0em
\item Notes: tbd
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
%\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]